# rosmake openrave_planning cannot be completed at all!

Tags: ros, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the "openrave_planning", so that I can connect both openrave and ros together, but whenever I try to build is, I get this error at 94% of the completion.

Here is the error:

```
[ 90%] Building CXX object python/bindings/CMakeFiles/openravepy_int.dir/openravepy_collisionchecker.cpp.o
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp: In member function ‘boost::python::api::object openravepy::PyKinBody::GetViewerData() const’:
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp:1998:47: warning: ‘virtual OpenRAVE::UserDataPtr OpenRAVE::KinBody::GetViewerData() const’ is deprecated (declared at /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/include/openrave/kinbody.h:1737) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp: In member function ‘boost::python::api::object openravepy::PyKinBody::GetPhysicsData() const’:
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp:2035:48: warning: ‘virtual OpenRAVE::UserDataPtr OpenRAVE::KinBody::GetPhysicsData() const’ is deprecated (declared at /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/include/openrave/kinbody.h:1756) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp: In member function ‘boost::python::api::object openravepy::PyKinBody::GetCollisionData() const’:
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_kinbody.cpp:2039:50: warning: ‘virtual OpenRAVE::UserDataPtr OpenRAVE::KinBody::GetCollisionData() const’ is deprecated (declared at /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/include/openrave/kinbody.h:1760) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Linking CXX executable openrave0.9
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_robot.cpp: In member function ‘openravepy::PyRobotBase::PyManipulatorPtr openravepy::PyRobotBase::SetActiveManipulator(int)’:
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_robot.cpp:794:44: warning: ‘virtual void OpenRAVE::RobotBase::SetActiveManipulator(int)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/include/openrave/robot.h:672) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_robot.cpp: In member function ‘int openravepy::PyRobotBase::GetActiveManipulatorIndex() const’:
/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/python/bindings/openravepy_robot.cpp:810:51: warning: ‘virtual int OpenRAVE::RobotBase::GetActiveManipulatorIndex() const’ is deprecated (declared at /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/include/openrave/robot.h:698) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/build'
[ 90%] Built target openrave
[ 91%] Building CXX object python/bindings/CMakeFiles/openravepy_int.dir/openravepy_controller.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object plugins/rplanners/CMakeFiles/rplanners.dir/linearsmoother.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [python/bindings/CMakeFiles/openravepy_int.dir/openravepy_kinbody.cpp.o] Error 4
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 92%] Building CXX object plugins/rplanners/CMakeFiles/rplanners.dir/randomized-astar.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object plugins/rplanners/CMakeFiles/rplanners.dir/workspacetrajectorytracker.cpp.o
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/plugins/rplanners/workspacetrajectorytracker.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool WorkspaceTrajectoryTracker::InitPlan(OpenRAVE::RobotBasePtr, OpenRAVE::PlannerBase::PlannerParametersConstPtr)’:
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/plugins/rplanners/workspacetrajectorytracker.cpp:74:27: warning: variable ‘tstate’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/plugins/rplanners/workspacetrajectorytracker.cpp: In member function ‘virtual OpenRAVE::PlannerStatus WorkspaceTrajectoryTracker::PlanPath(OpenRAVE::TrajectoryBasePtr)’:
  /home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/openrave_git/plugins/rplanners/workspacetrajectorytracker.cpp:163:31: warning: variable ‘fendtime’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
[ 93%] [ 94%] Building CXX object plugins/rplanners/CMakeFiles/rplanners.dir/parabolicsmoother.cpp.o
Building CXX object plugins/rplanners/CMakeFiles/rplanners.dir/pathoptimizers.cpp.o
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/build'
make[2]: *** [python/bindings/CMakeFiles/openravepy_int.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library librplanners.so
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/build'
[ 94%] Built target rplanners
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/karim/openrave_planning/openrave/build'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119696/rosmake-openrave_planning-cannot-be-completed-at-all!!/) by [Bondoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/10971/bondoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like you're hitting a bug in the compiler:

```
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

It sounds like you should ask about this on the [openrave mailing list](http://openrave-users-list.185357.n3.nabble.com/), along with the relevant information about your system, such as OS version, ROS version, and the version of the openrave stack that you're trying to compile.

As a side note, the openrave_planning stack hasn't been released since Fuerte, so I suspect is isn't very well supported in later versions of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0